# Variable name with subscripts in Manipulator[], is it possible?

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to create a variable in Manipulate[] with a subscript in its name with the following code:

```
{{Subscript[r, b], 175.0, "Base radius"}, 127.0, 254.0, 1.0, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
```

But, I've got an error message saying that the variable specification is incorrect.

Given that I can name variables like that outside Manipulator variables' specification, is it possible to overcome this behavior and define a Manipulator variable with such a name?

Best Regards,

Comment: Post a minimal working example. That means all the code we need to get the same error.

Comment: Its actually quite interesting numeric subscripts will work `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + Subscript[a, 1]x)], {x, 0, 6}], {Subscript[a, 1], 0, 2}]`  will.  Alpha subscripts `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + Subscript[a, i]x)], {x, 0, 6}], {Subscript[a, i], 0, 2}]` doesn't.  Also double quoting the subscript doesn't make a difference.  Possible bug?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you can `Set` the variable `Subscript[r, b]` to the value of the manipulator variable.

```
Manipulate[
 Subscript[r, b] = rb;
 f[Subscript[r, b]],
 {{rb, 175.0, "Base radius"}, 127.0, 254.0, 1.0,
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}]
```

[image]

Comment: Using HoldForm on the Variable is a nice little improvement.  `Manipulate[Subscript[r, b] = rb;
 f[rb], {{rb, 175.0, HoldForm@Subscript[r, b]}, 127.0, 254.0, 1.0, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}]`