# Why doesn't my Manipulate expression work?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I want to change 3 parameters: Subscript[I, dc], Subscript[B, dc], Subscript[μM, 0] and see changing on 2 graphs:

```
Plot[Evaluate[mx[t] /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, AxesLabel -> {t, mx}]
```

and

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[m[t] /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

My code:

```
m[t_] := {mx[t], my[t], mz[t]}

γ = 28;

h = 6.62*10^-34;

e = 1.6*10^-19;

Subscript[μ, 0] = 1.25*10^-6;

Subscript[μM, 0] = 800*10^-3;

Subscript[M, 0] = 0.64*10^6;

Subscript[r, 0] = 100*10^-9;

Subscript[l, 0] = 3*10^-9;

Subscript[I, dc] = 1*10^-3;

Subscript[B, dc] = 200*10^-3;

Subscript[α, G] = 0.01;

p = {0, 0, 1};

σ =(γ*h/2*e)*1/(Subscript[M, 0]*Pi*(Subscript[r, 0])^2)*Subscript[l, 0];

Subscript[B, eff] = {Subscript[B, dc], 0, 0}-Subscript[μM, 0]*(m[t]*p);

system1 ={D[m[t], t] ==γ*(Cross[Subscript[B, eff], m[t]]) + Subscript[α, G]*(Cross[m[t], D[m[t], t]]) +σ*Subscript[I, dc]*(Cross[m[t], Cross[m[t], p]]),(m[t] /. t -> 0) == {0, 1, 0}};

s1 = NDSolve[system1, m[t], {t, 0, 50}]

Plot[Evaluate[{mx[t], my[t], mz[t]} /. s1], {t, 0, 50},AxesLabel -> {t, m}]

Plot[Evaluate[mx[t] /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, AxesLabel -> {t, mx}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[m[t] /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I tried to use "Manipulate" but have mistakes and it's not working.
Below, how i tried to use "Manipulate"

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate[mx[t] /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, AxesLabel -> {t, mx}], 
  {Subscript[I, dc], 0.001, 100}]
```

The error message I get is:

> Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument {Subscript[I, dc],0.001,100} does not have the correct form for a variable specification.

Comment: general topic [**107628**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107628/5478) and probably a duplicate: [**85023**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85023/5478), do you agree?

Comment: do not use Subscript. Subscript should really be removed from future version of Mathematica  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 3):

As the message you are seeing is telling you, the form `Subscript[...]` is not allowed as a control variable name in a `Manipulate` expression. AFAIK only identifiers that would be accepted as variable names in a list of local variable specifications given to `DynamicModule` can be used.

However, your code wouldn't work even if you were to rename your subscripted variables to ordinary variables. You would still face the fundamental problem that the parameters, such as `Subscript[I, dc]`, have all been replaced by numerical values by the time `NDSolve` is evaluated.

`Manipulate` can only vary parameters in an expression that appear as symbols. You have no symbolic parameters in the plot expression you give to `Manipulate`. You just have a static plot where nothing can be varied.

You can see this by removing the semi-colon at the end of the expression the compute `system1`.

[image: system1]